# What is the process with Maven project to compile and test the code?

Tags: java, maven, process, installation, lifecycle

I have maven project imported in my eclipse. Now I need to start making changes to it and test it with the integration test (out of App server). Currently, the integration test is run out of server using openEJB container.

My basic question is, what is the regular process to compile, build and test with Maven?

1. `mvn install`
2. Maven -> Update Project.
3. Run my test from command line

Is it how it is done? I am specifically interested in knowing `mvn install` commands.
So should I do all three steps before I can test it?

Example: I just wanted to print something and see what is the output. For this I guess I need to do all these steps?

The openEJB container needs classes so it can load them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `mvn isntall` is the most popular option. It compiles, packages and tests your project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wonderful Maven quick-reference sheet at http://maven.apache.org/guides/MavenQuickReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be aware that unit tests and integration tests are separate and are run from separate plugins and at separate parts of the maven lifecycles.  Unit tests are run with [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and integration tests are run with [failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

You want to run integration tests and the failsafe documentation says:

> NOTE: when running integration tests, you should invoke maven with the (shorter to type too)
>
> `mvn verify`
>
> rather than trying to invoke the `integration-test` phase directly...

This is the best way to run integration tests *directly in maven*.  It will run all the preceding steps necessary (eg: `compile`) in order to run the integration tests.  It won't *waste* time doing an install because `install` happens immediately after `verify`.

But if you're running the tests locally, it may be a better idea to run your integration tests directly in your IDE.  That will give you a much faster feedback loop.

Comment: Simple question: If I do mvn compile, without install/package, does the new class files get included in the project and be available for my Integration test file. Integration test is one file and I am running it from command line.

Comment: Simple answer is, "no".  AFAIK, integration tests use the result of `package`.  Complicated answer is, you can't run `verify` without intrinsically running `package`.  `package` will get run, too.  You can skip all the preceding steps by running `failsafe:integration-test` and `failsafe:verify` directly, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Eclipse project the most reasonable thing is to do everything not from command line but from Eclipse. Assuming you have m2e plugin installed, go to `your_project->run as->Maven test` and run it.

You dont need neither `install` nor `package` phase to run Maven tests, `package` will create a jar which is not needed for tests, `install` will copy this jar to local repo which is also useless. When Maven run tests it uses compiled classes from target dir and ignores project's jar if even it exists.

Comment: Well. It has to build the whole project. And Integration Test is not included in the project. Its setup separately. Basically, the projects need to get updated with newer compiled library (classes). Should I still skip mvn install?

Comment: If Integration test is a separate project then if you run its tests from maven then it will use main project jar from local repo. If you run it from Eclipse it will use target/classes. To avoid confusion its better to run tests from Eclipse

Comment: Integration test is just ONE file and it does not have any pom. Its TestNG testing file. It just needs the classes/packages that it uses. My question is, how to get the updated classes to this file. So to generate I need to run mvn install/package or just compile? mvn compile, compiles and creates new classes. But how does my test program recognizes if the updates class files not in the build path?